# prevent from cloning or downloading (zip) Git repository

Tags: git, permissions, repository

I created a private repository on github for a project. I added 4 members on that repository. All are working from Monday to Friday on that project. My life fully depends on that project. I just want to preserve my repository from illegal access i.e. cloning (or zip) repo outside of office or cloning(or zip) repo on holidays (Saturday and Sunday) of those 4 members. I am watching that repository. But I am not sure if I will get notifications on illegal access of repo on github.

Anybody know about that?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to do. If they can clone your repo during the week in office, they can always put it on a thumb drive or CD or cloud drive or any of a thousand other places. Stopping them from working on the weekend doesn't prevent anything.

Comment: I also have a really, really hard time understanding what the problem is here. Might I suggest for you to answer the questions in a problem solving matrix, http://problemsolvingmatrix.wordpress.com/, to both come up with a more clear problem description for others to help you, and I would be surprised if the act of answering those questions will not be of direct help to you as well.

Comment: Hey @JoeEnos, I restricted USB access from all the pc's in my office. Even they cant access their email inside the office. I am only worry about the weekends. Because they can login on github from their home and they may download zip or clone my git repository. As I know github send notifications only if anybody creates any issue or comment or etc. It will not send any notification on clone or downloading zip.

Comment: Do you also restrict web access to DropBox, Google Drive, SkyDrive, Bitcasa, Box, Rapidshare, Megaupload, DilbertFiles, AWS, FTP, SSH, and every other website on the planet that allows file uploads? Including Github itself? (What's to stop them from uploading the code to their own private Github account?) Basically, if you can't trust your own programmers, then get new programmers. Software people are intelligent - if they want to steal your code, they will. Your best defense is a good legal contract, not trying to build your technology to be smarter than them - you'll fail.

Comment: @JoeEnos: Thanx, I know if they want to steal that project they have many different ways. Actually I am new to github. I thought there may be git feature to notify the repo owner by mail if anybody clone a repo or download a zip. Is there any feature exist on github ????

Answer (score 2):

Set up a cron job from your home machine that pulls the repo at 5.00pm on Friday and pushes it back up at 9.00am (or whenever working day starts) on Monday.  As long as *you* don't mess with it over the weekend it will stay safe.

However, as [Joe Enos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111266/joe-enos) says.  Why?  They could work on it on the weekend using their thumb drive copy and not push up any changes til  Wednesday at lunchtime.